# Storing List<Map<Enum,Object>> datatype as JSON in DynamoDb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

In Java, when using DynamoDbMapper, what is the best way to store `List<Map<Enum,Object>>` datatype as JSON? Which annotations should we use to achieve this? In our case, the Enum could be serialized into a simple string, while the Object could be serialized into JSON string.

Also, could anyone clarify in which situation one must use each of these annotations `@DynamoDBTypeConverter`, `@DynamoDBTypeConvertedJson`, and `@DynamoDbDocument`?

Comment: How many enum values are there? Is that number fairly static? Do the enum values correspond to a particular type of object?

Comment: 3 enum values. Enum is a simple string value. I can serialize and deserialize it with @DynamoDBTypeConverter